# Navigation controller dont work

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have three view controllers in my storyboard.

In second controller I have navigation controller embeded. Second controller is connected to third with segue.

From first view controller, I call second one by `presentViewController`. In presented view controller I press a button that trigger a segue. What I expect is to see navigation controller in second and third view controller, but third viewcontroller is also shows from bottom to top with out navigation controller.

How to make nav controller visible in second and third view controller ?

Comment: if you have connected using segue. use `performSegueWithIdentifier` method in code.

Comment: yes I use this method

Comment: you said you use `presentViewController` inside your question

Comment: yes, i did say that. i use presentviewcontroller in first controller, and perform in second.

Comment: presenting will modally present the VC and therefore the navigation view controller stack won't be in it

Comment: Can you show your storyboard and code?

Answer (score 0):

Select the **segue**

> between your secondView and thirdView in your StoryBoard

and look it has this settings:

[image: Look its kind if type Show]

Take care the identifier is what you want, the key here is the kind type of segue